# AWS, EFS, EKS, Mount volume as root

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount a volume as root.

I am using aws-efs-csi-driver v1.3.0 on Kubernetes 1.17 in EKS and trying to use Dynamic Provisioning.

My issue is that no matter how I try to specify the UID/GID, it still creates it with a dynamically allocated UID and GID.

Here are my resources:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-ddd8b9e9
  directoryPerms: "775"
  uid: "0"
  gid: "0"
reclaimPolicy: Retain

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: test-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: ubuntu:latest
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
          args: [ "-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /example/out.txt; sleep 5; done" ]
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-data
              mountPath: /data
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsGroup: 0
        fsGroup: 0
      volumes:
        - name: test-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-pvc
```

My issue is that I want the data directory to have the `root:root` permissions, and not the dynamically allocated permissions (`50004:50004` in this case)

```
❯ kubectl exec -it test-9588c455c-qqdw6 -- bash
root@test-9588c455c-qqdw6:/# ls -las
total 4
0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root    29 Oct 15 09:44 .
0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root    29 Oct 15 09:44 ..
0 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root  root     0 Oct 15 09:44 .dockerenv
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root     7 Sep 21 16:48 bin -> usr/bin
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root     6 Apr 15  2020 boot
4 drwxrwxr-x   2 50004 50004 6144 Oct 15 09:44 data
0 drwxr-xr-x   5 root  root   360 Oct 15 09:44 dev
0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root    66 Oct 15 09:44 etc
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root     6 Apr 15  2020 home
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root     7 Sep 21 16:48 lib -> usr/lib
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root     9 Sep 21 16:48 lib32 -> usr/lib32
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root     9 Sep 21 16:48 lib64 -> usr/lib64
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root    10 Sep 21 16:48 libx32 -> usr/libx32
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root     6 Sep 21 16:48 media
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root     6 Sep 21 16:48 mnt
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root     6 Sep 21 16:48 opt
0 dr-xr-xr-x 415 root  root     0 Oct 15 09:44 proc
0 drwx------   2 root  root    37 Sep 21 17:00 root
0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root    21 Oct 15 09:44 run
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root     8 Sep 21 16:48 sbin -> usr/sbin
0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root     6 Sep 21 16:48 srv
0 dr-xr-xr-x  13 root  root     0 Jun 11 09:16 sys
0 drwxrwxrwt   2 root  root     6 Sep 21 17:00 tmp
0 drwxr-xr-x  13 root  root   145 Sep 21 16:48 usr
0 drwxr-xr-x  11 root  root   139 Sep 21 17:00 var
root@test-9588c455c-qqdw6:/# exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed annoying... in short, the UID/GID we specified will be ignored. Please take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/300#issuecomment-824911126). If your workload requires same UID/GID as the mounted volume, a workaround is add code to runas the same UID/GID as the mounted volume in entrypoint script.